# Setting up reference images with empties - scales wrong

Tags: image, scale

I'm setting up reference images for a car model.
I've found a suitable blueprint and cropped each view with Photoshop.
I've saved each cropped image seperately for use in blender, spending some time so that the pixel size of the images match. They are not quite perfect - but close enough to get a good idea of where the misalignments might be.

So:
The FRONT view image is 700 pixels wide x 500 pixels high.
The REAR view image is 700w x 500h
The TOP view is 768w x 1823h
The LEFT side view is 1823w x 500h

but something crazy happens when I add an empty and select these images :

[image: scale wrong]

Although the front view is actually 700 x 500 pixels it's way too big !

Strangely, if i rotate the front view 90 degrees - it appears to be the same size as the length of the side view and the top view !

[image: scale wrong 2]

any ideas ?

thanks - this is really confusing !

Comment: can you just scale the front view down with s until it is the right size?

Comment: It is the right size - it's 700 x 500.

Comment: Worked this out I think. 

The best way to do this is to lay out the various views on one large SQUARE image. 
 
It's important that its square, but doesn't really matter what size the images are as long as they are relatively scaled to each other. 

Then move the images around to position the required view.

Comment: I have the same exact problem, how did you end up solving this ?